# Google Analytics API max-results

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics API for R using rga library. I would like to by pass the 1000 rows limit with max-results:

```
result <- ga$getData(id, start.date="2014-09-01", end.date="2014-09-30", metrics = "ga:pageviews",dimensions = "ga:pagePath,ga:previousPagePath",sort = "-ga:pageViews",filters = "ga:pagePath=~.html;ga:previousPagePath=~operating_system", max-results = 10000)
```

But I get the following error :

```
Error: unexpected '='
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library maps 'max' to 'max-results' in the Google API - try changing 'max-results' to 'max'.

relevant library code:
https://github.com/skardhamar/rga/blob/1e0b06a03274ad57058724eaf95ad285264fc5c1/R/core.R

Google Analytics API (note, no 'max' param):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use currently to get a limit of for example 10:

**Reporting API v3**

```
"max_results": 10
```

[**Reporting API v4**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_size)

```
"pageSize": 10
```